# Using Search webpart on page with list

Tags: sharepoint-online, search, search-results

I could use some help with the following problem: I have a list that has been put on a page as a webpart. I need to put a search on this page that returns only the results from that list.

Therefore, I have put a search box on that page that sends queries to a custom results page. On that page I have a search results webpart where I'm trying to set the keyword filter to 'only return lists and libraries', but I have no idea how to go further from here. I have been reading a lot of online stuff about how to use search, but it only complicates things more and can't really find a straight answer to my problem.

[image: Search in list]

If there's a better solution to achieve this, I hope someone here can show me.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: http://splistfilter.vitalyzhukov.com/ - hope it would be useful too

Comment: Thx, but I'm unable to deploy solutions. No admin rights here...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For above you can create a seperate result source or you can specify th direct query as your specifying:

Just update the query with below

```
{searchTerms} Path:http://YourSiteUrl/Lists/YourListName
```

think will help you up returning the result

Answer (score 2):

To enhance Sunils sugestion, you should add " -contentclass:STS_List_* " in order to exclude landing pages such as allitems.aspx

Comment: So it becomes:
{searchTerms} Path:http://YourSiteUrl/Lists/YourListName -contentclass:STS_List_*